# Difficulty in compiling TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I downloaded the most recent version of TypeScript and NodeJS, obtained a small example in TypeScript, and attempted to compile using both Node terminal and a Windows 10 command line. Please see below:

The sample program I'm using is:

```
let greeting:string = "Hello!";
console.log(greeting);
```

```
C:\Users\CaitlinG>tsc greet.ts
node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts:482:22 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PromiseConstructor'.

482     promiseLibrary?: PromiseConstructor;
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts:1706:26 - error TS2507: Type 'MapConstructor' is not a constructor function type.

1706     class Map<V> extends global.Map<string, V> {
                              ~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts:1716:37 - error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `l
ib` compiler option to es2015 or later.

1716   interface GlobalMap<K, V> extends Map<K, V> {}
                                         ~~~

node_modules/@types/webgl2/index.d.ts:582:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'WebGL2RenderingConte
xt' must be of type '{ new (): WebGL2RenderingContext; prototype: WebGL2RenderingContext; readonly ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES: number; readonly ACTIVE_TEXTURE:
 number; ... 556 more ...; readonly WAIT_FAILED: number; }', but here has type '{ new (): WebGL2RenderingContext; prototype: WebGL2RenderingContext; r
eadonly ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES: number; readonly ACTIVE_TEXTURE: number; ... 557 more ...; readonly MAX_CLIENT_WAIT_TIMEOUT_WEBGL: number; }'.

582 declare var WebGL2RenderingContext: {
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:16316:13
    16316 declare var WebGL2RenderingContext: {
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'WebGL2RenderingContext' was also declared here.
```

I don't understand how to resolve these issues.

Comment: Either you are not showing us all of `greet.ts` or something is very wrong with your system.

Comment: Share your tsconfig.

Comment: Create a new folder in the root of a drive. Create a new text file in that folder. Copy just those two lines into that text file. Rename the text file `greet.ts`. Open the Windows Command Line. Navigate to the new folder you created. Type `tsc greet.ts` and press Enter. If you still get those same errors, then we'll have something to discuss.

Comment: I'm guessing your `tsconfig` is missing the appropriate `compilerOptions.target` and `compilerOptions.lib` settings.

Comment: A quick drop of your code in [a codesandbox environment](https://codesandbox.io/embed/lucid-dubinsky-l5s8s?file=/index.ts) shows it's working as expected. I suspect a configuration issue, as the stack trace is complaining about a constructor from `@types/mongodb`, which isn't referenced from your source (at least not directly).

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2LkzLv2U

Comment: I created a folder, built the config file, attempted to compile, and the result was the same. I pasted a copy of my config file above (link). Thanks.

Comment: I uninstalled Node, reinstalled it (which removed the @types/mongodb error), compiled and...same error. Can someone explain how to edit the compilerOptions.target and compilerOptions.lib settings?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following in your tsconfig.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "es6"]
}
```

Comment: The errors were still there, but the js file was created. This seems very strange. I'm using the newest version of Node, 14.4.0. Could this pose a problem?

Comment: Did u tried exiting from the node terminal and re-running it again ?

Comment: Inside vscode or running node on the command line, then running the typescript program at the node prompt, '>'?

Comment: exit from all the terminal , open only one either command line or vs code's terminal, and run the command again

Comment: OK. I did that. The errors are still there. I ran: tsc greet.ts on the command line (not in vscode). I added "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "es6"]
}

Comment: @crashmstr I posted a link to my tsconfig file.

Comment: Okay I checked that, Can you try doing  `npm install @types/mongodb` and check ? After that delete your node_modules folder and do a npm install again.

Comment: Hi @Shijil. I tried following your suggestions several times and the error is still there. Could it be an issue with my system path? Thanks.

Comment: Solved! I had a copy of the node_modules folder in my home directory, 'C:\Users\CaitlinG'. Once I deleted it, the program compiled without any issues. Thank you for the help Shijil Narayanan.

Comment: Yes I had suggested you to deleted the node_modules , great it worked :)